# Location.distanceTo not giving correct results in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to calculate the distance between two locations (Current location with the previous location).

So I tried the following:

```
Location previousLocation = new Location("");
previousLocation.setLatitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLatitude", 0f));
previousLocation.setLongitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLongitude", 0f));
float distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
totalDistanceInMeters += distance;
editor.putFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", totalDistanceInMeters);
Log.e("Location Update","totalDistance"+totalDistanceInMeters);     
if (totalDistanceInMeters > 1)
{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total UpdateLocation"+totalDistanceInMeters/1609, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Log.e("Alert","Update");
}
```

To test the above code. The first time result was perfect and when it triggered the second time. The phone was in the same location but I am getting distances like 141.0111 m. thrid time 304.0011 m. Am I doing something wrong here?

The results are not showing up correctly. According to doc online the results are in metres.

Is there an easy way to calculate the difference between the first location results with the second one and if it is more than 10m I would like to do some other calculation if not just keep quite.

Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you even using the following code

```
float distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
totalDistanceInMeters += distance;
```

That adds up the previous distance to present distance and gives the added value everytime....

example

```
first time 
distance between A and B is 100 m
second time
distance between A and B is 100 m+100 m=200 m
```

so try using distance directly in toast

```
float distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
if (totalDistanceInMeters > 1)
{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total UpdateLocation"+distance/1609,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Log.e("Alert","Update");
}
```

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize I had that piece code before check total distance. Actually, that calculation was for different thing. Anyways, I moved that after checking the total distance that solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think accuracy needs to be set in order to get the exact distance. Also try to get hold of the previous and current locations manually so as to calculate the distance and verify.